# how to get nhibernate to recognize a schema change

Tags: nhibernate, schema, mapping

I have nHibernate working quite well on my brand new database.  In fact it was quite helpful to have it generate the schema based on the mapping files.

However, I now have data in my tables and I need to start updating the schema.  I don't want to use SchemaExport as that drops all the tables.  I don't want to use SchemaUpdate as I need some non-null columns.  That leaves me with manual updates to the database.  This is okay.

I make the changes and then run my unit tests.  And they fail, but only some of them.

The queries that use .CreateCriteria return the data from the newly added columns
The queries that use .CreateQuery do not include any data from the newly added columns

Any ideas why the difference is occurring?

Comment: Are you serializing the configuration? If so you will need to blow away the file. Otherwise providing that your mappings are correct it should pick up the schema changes.

Comment: The mappings are the only thing NH knows about your schema...

Comment: it was a rookie mistake.  the mapping file for one of the entities was not an embedded resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your CreateQuery methods are working on raw HQL strings it could be as simple (and tedious) as updating them.

Comment: It was a rookie mistake.  One of the mapping file was not marked as 'embedded content'.  updated that and everything works!